# Did Sean Spicer tweet a password twice in two days?

Tags: politics, security

This article came up in my news feed and I immediately called shenanigans on it: White House Press Secretary, [Sean Spicer Just Tweeted Something That Looks an Awful Lot Like a Password](https://usuncut.com/politics/sean-spicer-tweeted-account-passwords/)

Recently, [Sean Spicer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sean_Spicer#White_House_Press_Secretary) has been the butt of internet jokes, memes and general internet scorn, and even [scepticism](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36834/were-additional-fencing-and-magnetometers-used-on-the-national-mall-for-trumps) on this [site](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36836/was-president-trumps-inauguration-the-first-time-that-floor-coverings-have) so this [feels](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36832/did-trumps-inauguration-draw-the-largest-ever-audience-to-a-us-inauguration) like more of [the same](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/36870/has-there-been-a-dramatic-expansion-of-the-u-s-federal-workforce-in-recent-year).

The articles claims Sean Spicer tweeted (something that looks like) his twitter password, but then deleted the tweets. After seeing the alleged tweets, they look like passwords - both 8 characters, combination of letters and numbers.

**Did Sean Spicer tweet those 8 character strings?**

For security/legal reasons I'm not asking the are/were passwords. Or for which service. The article also says "*don’t try to access Sean Spicer’s Twitter*". And I agree.

Comment: "The president is tweeting!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The White House [acknowledged that the tweets were made](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2017/01/26/a-short-investigation-into-the-mysterious-tweets-from-press-secretary-sean-spicer/?tid=hybrid_collaborative_2_na), calling them "pocket tweets."

As for their content, WaPo speculates that they're two-factor authentication codes which he sent back to the SMS number that Twitter uses, rather than entering into the device he was using to log in.

Comment: I freely admit I've almost done something similar on occasion, when I wasn't watching whether my IM window or my authenticator window had focus. It's still embarassing when it happens.

Comment: Twitter's SMS two-factor authentication codes are *six numeric* (0-9) digits. So it doesn't look like one of those.